# React only display components of array properties that exist

Tags: reactjs

I want to only display the following components if their href property exists:

```
 <ExternalLinks href={source}>Code</ExternalLinks>
 <ExternalLinks href={download}>Download</ExternalLinks>
 <ExternalLinks href={visit}>Website</ExternalLinks>
```

Here is the array, for example if the download and visit properties don't exist for the array object then I don't want them to appear.

```
    title: '',
    description: "",
    image: '/images/ethereumcampaign.png',
    tags: ['React', 'Node.js', 'Solidity'],
    href: "/campaigns",
    //download: 'https://google.com',
    source: '',
    //visit: "",
    id: 0,
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to `filter` before `map` `tags.filter(t => t.visit).map(...)`

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 ways:

1. filtering:

   ```
       {tags.filter((tag) => tag.download && tag.visit).map((tag, i) => (
           <Tag key={i}>{tag.title}</Tag>
           <Tag key={i}>{tag.description}</Tag>
           ...
         ))}
     </TagList>
   ```
2. using backquotes (``):

   ```
       {tags.map((tag, i) => (`
         ${tag.visit && tag.download ? <Tag key={i}>{tag}</Tag> : ""}
      `))}
     </TagList>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Filter your data before doing mapping, `hasOwnProperty()` determines the `presence` of `properties` download and visit in your `tag` object:

```
   <TagList>
        {tags
          .filter((tag) => tag.hasOwnProperty('download') && tag.hasOwnProperty('visit'))
          .map((tag, i) => (
            <Tag key={i}>{tag}</Tag>
          ))}
      </TagList>
```

Comment: hasOwnProperty will return true for properties that exist, but are undefined. I think the better option would be to compare the property to undefined. `tag.download !== undefined`

Comment: I think @Dupocas  wants to display tags that have both properties download and visit, he can tell us which use case he wants.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that he only wants to display tags where download and visit are not undefined. What would be the point of rendering a download link with an undefined href?